# Why is dummy loop consuming kernel time?

Tags: c++, time

I wrote this simple, useless program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define TABSIZE 256*1024*1024

int main(){
    volatile int *tab = new int[TABSIZE];

    cerr << "start" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<TABSIZE;i+=1)
        tab[i] *= i;
    cerr << "stop" << endl;

    delete []tab;
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it (witch O2) and running with `time ./a.out` I was really surprised at the results:

```
real    0m1,660s
user    0m0,462s
sys     0m1,177s
```

Clearly, most of the time is spent in kernel space, even though main loop has nothing to do with any syscalls. I can see string `start` immediately after program start, so `new` does not consume much time. Cognately, `stop` shows up just before end.

So, the question is: Why so much time is spent in kernel space?
I use GCC 7.4 on Linux 4.15.

Comment: Most of that time is spent allocating and initializing memory, I suspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
volatile int *tab = new int[TABSIZE];
```

This statement allocates 1 GiB of RAM. This amount is marked in the page table of the process as used, but not really initialized nor made available (the pages are marked as "not present").

```
tab[i] *= i
```

At this point, the first access to a new page (usually 4KiB) results in a Page Fault, which is handled by the kernel, which then initializes a range of memory with zeros and marks the page as present. Then, until the next page, the acesses happen without page faults.

This memory management is the reason for kernel CPU usage.

Comment: Great explanation. On my system, if I add `memset(tab, 0, sizeof(int)*TABSIZE);` before the loop, it will reduce kernel time; however at the expense of more user time spent.

Comment: @TobySpeight note that `tab` is a `int*` here. Simpler and more wrong in this case. I also fell for it at first.

Comment: @ypnos Doh! (and it's dynamically allocated for good reason, too - though `std::vector` would relieve us of the manual memory management).  I withdraw my criticism.